# drop in place all but specified columns by name from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data:

```
library(data.table)
data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)
```

I have some vectors of names of columns I would like to keep:

```
some_keep <- c('mpg','cyl')
more_keep <- c('disp','hp')
```

I want to drop-in-place every column except those named in `some_keep` and `more_keep`.

I know that I can use `setdiff` with `names`:

```
mtcars[, ( setdiff(names(mtcars),c(some_keep,more_keep)) ) := NULL] # this works
```

But this seems not very readable.  I know that to **select** all but these, I can use `with=FALSE`:

```
mtcars[,-c(some_keep,more_keep), with=FALSE] # returns the columns I want to drop
```

But then this doesn't work:

```
mtcars[,(-c(some_keep,more_keep)):=NULL] # invalid argument to unary operator
```

Nor do these:

```
mtcars[,-c(some_keep,more_keep)] <- NULL # invalid argument to unary operator
mtcars[,-c(some_keep,more_keep), with=FALSE] <- NULL # unused argument (with = FALSE)
```

Is there a simpler `data.table` expression that doesn't require writing the table's name twice?

Please note that this [seemingly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565869/r-how-to-delete-all-columns-in-a-dataframe-except-a-specified-few-by-string) is really asking about selecting (not dropping) all but specified as shown above.

Comment: I mentioned this on a similar FR a few months ago: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1710#issuecomment-280684187

Comment: Not dropping in place, but `mtcars[, .SD, .SDcols=c(some_keep, more_keep)]` returns the desired result.

Comment: What if we took your working code and made it readable: `drop_cols = setdiff(names(mtcars), c(some_keep, more_keep))` and then `mtcars[, drop_cols := NULL] `.

Comment: Really, I think I'm just going to vote to close as opinion-based. You've got a single line solution that works well. You can make it more readable by breaking it into two lines. Neither "elegant" nor "readable" is an objective criteria for evaluating other methods.

Comment: I agree with Gregor 's suggestion and do it that way myself. There's a typo in it, though: it should be like `(drop_cols) :=`. I have no opinion on close or leave open, though I think it *could* be made objective: "How can I select columns to keep by reference without writing the table's name twice?" The answer would probably be to create a wrapper function, `keepcols <- function(DT, k, d = setdiff(names(DT), k)) DT[, (d) := NULL ][]`

Comment: @Frank thanks, I feel validated. I'll write a wrapper function.  I don't have the fortitude to attempt a syntax change and pull request